# jQuery .find() not working on $.post() data

Tags: ajax, jquery, find, .post

I made a simple example showing the problem: the form below submits to another page using jQuery `.post()`.

**Form**

```
$('form').submit(function(){

    $.post(
        $(this).attr('action'),
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(data) {
            var ret = data;
            var final_data = $(ret).find('#holder-1').html();
            alert(final_data);
        }
    )
    return false;

})
```

**Action**

```
<div id="holder-1">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
</div>

<div id="holder-2">
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
</div>

<div id="holder-3">
    <h1>Content 3</h1>
</div>
```

The log shows that the content of `data` looks fine. But once i try to find `#holder-1` with `.find()`, it returns **undefined**.

This is almost the same as the **last example** in the jQuery api page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Here is the full (not) working example hosted in my website, with some `console.log()` along the code:

**Form:** http://www.peixelaranja.com.br/tmp/post.php

I tried nearly anything: passing the dataType as 4th parameter, using `$.ajax()` instead of `.post()`, using `.filter()` instead of `.find()`, different versions of jQuery... Nothing seems to work.

All the files are **UTF-8**.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `ret`?

Comment: `filter` did work for me, both on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you mentioned that you used `filter` instead of `find`, however, that should work.  jQuery is stripping out the `html`, `head`,`body` tags, etc.  Once this is done, `#holder-1` is now at the top level of the hierarchy.

This fiddle demonstrates that `filter` does work:

http://jsfiddle.net/68jEt/

```
var html = '<!doctype html><html dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR"><head>  <meta charset="UTF-8">  <title>Return Test</title></head><body> <div id="holder-1">     <h1>Content 1</h1>  </div>  <div id="holder-2">     <h1>Content 2</h1>  </div>  <div id="holder-3">     <h1>Content 3</h1>  </div></body></html>';

alert($(html).filter("#holder-1").html());
```